# What am I doing wrong with this loop in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the question that I'm trying to answer:

3. Write a script that calculates the common factors between 10 and 20. To find a common factor, you can use the modulo operator (%) to check whether a number can be evenly divided into both numbers. Then, this script should print lines that display the common factors like this:

   Common factors of 10 and 20

   1

   2

   5

Here is my code:

```
    USE MyGuitarShop;

    IF OBJECT_ID ('test') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE test;

    CREATE PROCEDURE test ()
    BEGIN 
    DECLARE counter INT
    DECLARE fact10 INT;
    DECLARE fact20 INT;
    DECLARE factors varchar (100);

    SET fact10 = 10;
    SET fact20 = 20;
    SET counter = 1;
    SET factors = 'Factors of 10 and 20';

    WHILE (counter <= 10/2) DO
        IF (fact10 % OF counter = 0 AND fact20 % OF counter = 0) THEN
        SET factors = CONTACT (factors, counter, ' ');
    END;
```

This is the error that I keep getting:

```
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test, Line 6
    Incorrect syntax near ')'.
    Msg 155, Level 15, State 2, Procedure test, Line 8
    'INT' is not a recognized CURSOR option.
    Msg 155, Level 15, State 2, Procedure test, Line 9
    'INT' is not a recognized CURSOR option.
    Msg 155, Level 15, State 2, Procedure test, Line 10
    'INT' is not a recognized CURSOR option.
    Msg 155, Level 15, State 2, Procedure test, Line 11
    'varchar' is not a recognized CURSOR option.
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test, Line 18
    Incorrect syntax near 'DO'.
    Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test, Line 19
    Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'OF'.
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you writing this as a database stored procedure?  That seems like a very odd (and poor) choice of tool for this purpose.

Comment: I found something online that used it like this,  how would you suggest going about it?  I was think of maybe using a temporary database.

Comment: Are you sure this is MySQL? OBJECT_ID is an MS-SQL function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message as well as the code indicates that you are using MS SQL Server. If this is the case you need to prefix local variables with an `@` sign, and also the counter needs to be incremented in the while loop or you'll be stuck in an infinite loop.

This code works with MSSQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @counter INT
    DECLARE @fact10 INT
    DECLARE @fact20 INT
    DECLARE @factors varchar (100)

    SET @fact10 = 10;
    SET @fact20 = 20;
    SET @counter = 1;
    SET @factors = 'Factors of 10 and 20: ' + char(13);

    WHILE (@counter <= 10/2) -- this really should be <= 10
       BEGIN
          IF ( @fact10 %  @counter = 0 AND @fact20 % @counter = 0)
            SET @factors = CONCAT (@factors, @counter, ' ', char(13));
       SET @counter = @counter + 1;
       END
       SELECT @factors
END;
```

The output would be:

```
Factors of 10 and 20: 
1 
2 
5
```

Why anyone would want to do this in SQL besides as a programming exercise I don't understand though.

Using a numbers table you could do the same thing as a simple select query:

```
-- the table master..spt_values.numbers holds integers 0-2047
select number from master..spt_values where type = 'P'
and number > 0 and 10 % number = 0 and 20 % number = 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much I will try this out when I come back to the question.  My book really didn't help me with this because the example uses a temporary table.

Comment: @JoshuaWright Btw, the condition in the loop breaks at 5 and thus excludes 10 from the answers even though it is a factor of both 10 and 20. The loop should run up to the lower number.

Answer (score 0):

First, the common factors of 10 and 20 should be 1, 2, 5 and 10.  Assuming you're using `mysql` and need to create a procedure to do this, here's a working example:

```
create procedure foobar(var1 int, var2 int)
begin
  declare counter int default 1;
  declare msg varchar(100) default '';

  while counter <= least(var1,var2) do
    if var1 mod counter = 0 and var2 mod counter = 0 then
      set msg = concat(msg, if(msg='','',','), counter);
    end if;
    set counter = counter + 1;
  end while;

  select msg;
end
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82220/1)

---

Here's a SQL Server equivalent:

```
create procedure foobar 
  @var1 int, @var2 int
as 
begin
  declare @counter int = 1;
  declare @msg varchar(100) = '';

  while @counter <= @var1 and @counter <= @var2
  begin
    if (@var1 % @counter = 0 and @var2 % @counter = 0)
      set @msg = concat(@msg, case when @msg='' then '' else ',' end, @counter);
    set @counter = @counter + 1;
  end

  select @msg;
end
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3680f/1)